# If I have minecraft already downloaded and I make a new account will I have to pay again?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I have Minecraft already downloaded and I make a new account will I have to pay again? I want to make an account for my friend using my other computer that already has Minecraft on it but I don't want to pay again, but I don't want them to use my account so do I have to pay even If I already have Minecraft downloaded and I make a new account?

Comment: Of course, the account is exactly what you buy. You can't just get unlimited accounts for unlimited people for free.

Comment: Why not answer? "# Yes" is an acceptable answer, when context is not required.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you do have to pay again. The account is what you buy, not the Minecraft software itself. You can download the Minecraft software anytime you want, but if you want to create a new account for your friend, either you or him have to pay to get a new account.